# Copying certain file extensions with VBS

Tags: vbscript, directory, copying

I'm trying to copy a multiple files with a certain extension to a different folder, heres the code I'm using, not too familiar with VBS, but could someone point me in the right direction?

```
dim filesys

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "V:\Auto Audiowall Music Uploads\MUSIC\"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Wscript.Echo objFolder.Path

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

For Each objFile in colFiles

If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "MP3" Then
objFSO.CopyFile "V:\Auto Audiowall Music Uploads\MUSIC\".objFile.Name.".mp3", "V:\Auto Audiowall     Uploads\New Music"
End If
If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "WAV" Then
objFSO.CopyFile "V:\Auto Audiowall Music Uploads\MUSIC\".objFile.Name.".wav", "V:\Auto Audiowall Uploads\New Music"
End If
Next
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Trying to copy multiple files with a certain extension to a different folder, unsure on the code

Comment: Sorry, the code is not working, there is an error saying that the file specified could not be found, ah

Comment: i'd like to know if multiple extensions can be combined in a single copy statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're concatenating your strings incorrectly in your `CopyFile` function. You need to use an ampersand (`&`) to concatenate strings in VBScript.

Rather than that, though, you can use `objFile.Path` instead of concatenating strings to create the full source path.

```
objFSO.CopyFile objFile.Path, "V:\Auto Audiowall Uploads\New Music\"
```

Or you can just use the `File` object's `Copy` function:

```
objFile.Copy "V:\Auto Audiowall Uploads\New Music\"
```

In either case, end the destination path with a slash so that VBScript knows that you're copying into a *folder* and not copying to create a new *file*.

Comment: The File object's method to copy (itself) is called .Copy (not .CopyFile); cf. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6973t06a%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Thanks for catching that. Updated.